# shadowbox opens images onto new page

Tags: javascript, html, css, shadowbox

i am trying to use shadowbox.js to open an image on top of the current web page. However when i click the link it takes me to my image and the page underneath goes to a blank page. Does anyone know how to open the shadowbox while keeping my current page underneath?

Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <script src="shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body onload="Shadowbox.init();">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="ss1.jpg" rel="shadowbox[screenshots]">image #1</a></td>
            <td><a href="ss2.jpg" rel="shadowbox[screenshots]">image #1</a></td>
            <td><a href="ss3.jpg" rel="shadowbox[screenshots]">image #1</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

Comment: not yet... I have other javascripts (jquery mobile js and css files) which i also call which causes shadowbox to mess up.

Comment: did you ever find what was the problem, I have the same issue using fancybox and jquery mobile

Answer (score 0):

Add the `Shadowbox.init()` to the `<head>` as the documentation suggests. Possibly put the CSS link first; again as the documentation suggests. The following should go into the head/

```
<script src="shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">
 Shadowbox.init();
</script>
```

Source: http://www.shadowbox-js.com/usage.html

Working Page Below:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="shadowbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="shadowbox.css" type="text/css">
 <script type="text/javascript">
   Shadowbox.init();
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="ss1.jpg" rel="shadowbox[screenshots]">image #1</a></td>
        <td><a href="ss2.jpg" rel="shadowbox[screenshots]">image #2</a></td>
        <td><a href="ss3.jpg" rel="shadowbox[screenshots]">image #3</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just tried and it still opens it on a page where the background is blank. Any other suggestions?

Comment: no luck. i copied all the files from the shadowbox folder and the images into my root folder and it still doesnt work

Comment: the section of my code which is to show the image is exactly like urs (minus the image names)... safari and firebox both display the image on a blank page how ever when i try to run it on ie it keeps telling me theres and error in the shadowbox.js file in line 17064

Comment: internet explorer says theres an invalid argument... when i went into the line in shadowbox.js it has:  _{aS.style[aQ]=""+aT+"px"}_